# Installation of Kivy problem (Python, Anaconda, VS Code)

Tags: kivy

I am trying to install Kivy and get it working in python (with VS Code through Anaconda). I went to the Anaconda Prompt and typed:
"conda install -c conda-forge kivy". I have 2 questions.

After installing it says: "Could Not Find C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\xxx.bat"
Here, "xxx" is just a replacement for a lot of letters.

(1) Is this a problem?

After having installed I try to run the following code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OizjT.png)

Could you guys explain to me, why the App doesn't show up on my screen, after I run the code?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say that I solved it by changing the code to the following:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

# Make Sure This Is Always the last import
from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')


# Main Code
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="TEST")


# Run This Thing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```